# Oracle : cannot perform a DML operation inside a query error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I have following query which works but in one part of it I want to call this function pbweb.adposter.MakeDeepLinkEx and get the value back as url1 but i get the following error:

EE in pbk26w60.GenerateDeepLink: ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query

I sort of understand why this is happening as the function must be trying to alter the db inside the select which is not permitted.

I get that I need to do something like :

```
declare
retvar varchar2(500);
begin
    retvar := pbweb.adposter.MakeDeepLinkEx('119686','1368256');
end;
```

which executes but I dont know where to go from here? I am not well versed in PLSQL and have been stuck with trying to fix this issue while the person who wrote all this is on holiday.

Is there any way to get this to return the value from MakeDeepLinkEx within the current query or without altering it to much? If i try add begin, end etc into the query it just breaks.

```
$sql = "SELECT a.ad_id,
                a.headline, a.pay_period_id,
                (select value from ad_fields where field_id='Jobtitle' and ad_id=a.ad_id) as job_title,
                (select value from ad_fields where field_id='Department' and ad_id=a.ad_id) as department,
                (select value from ad_fields where field_id='Job_Description' and ad_id=a.ad_id) as job_desc,
                (select value from ad_fields where field_id='Champney_Benefits' and ad_id=a.ad_id) as benefits,
                (select value from ad_fields where field_id='Champney_Salary' and ad_id=a.ad_id) as sal_desc,
                a.salary,
                a.salary_max,
              
                (select value from ad_fields where field_id='Location' and ad_id=a.ad_id) as location,
                a.postcode,
                a.email,
                :url || pbweb.pbk00w24.p_encode (
                        null,
                        null,
                        null, 
                        :acc_id , 
                        null, 
                        (select visibility_code from advertisement_visibilities where ad_id = a.ad_id and rownum = 1), 
                        a.ad_id, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null
                ) || CHR(38) AS url,
                pbweb.adposter.MakeDeepLinkEx(a.user_id,a.ad_id) as url1
                from
                advertisements a
                JOIN advertisement_visibilities b ON a.ad_id=b.ad_id
                where a.acc_id = :acc_id AND a.status = 'P' AND start_dt < sysdate AND end_dt >= sysdate and b.visibility_code=:vis";


    $jobs = db_getAll($sql, array(':acc_id' => '202020', ':url' => ADVERT_URL, ':vis' => 'TJP'));
```

Comment: We have no way of knowing what MakeDeepLinkEx does if you don't post the code.  OT, are you really using Oracle 9i, from 1998?

Comment: yeah its a joke of a legacy system. Its kind of irrelevant what MakeDeepLinkEx actually does i just need to find a way to call it within the select

Comment: @user794846 - As I point out in my answer, it is actually really important to determine exactly what the function does because you'll need to guarantee that it's not going to create problems for your system if you call the function with every possible set of parameters (even those that are filtered out by joins or by predicates in the `where` clause).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle works very hard to ensure that `select` queries are read-only.  If you want to create a query that modifies data, you have to work exceptionally hard to bypass these safeguards.  And be willing to put up with some pretty hacky solutions.

**If you are going to do this, you absolutely must determine what `MakeDeepLinkEx` actually does and make sure that letting Oracle call this function with whatever parameters the optimizer thinks appropriate (including rows that are filtered out in the `where` clause) won't cause any problems to your system.**  You're asking Oracle to bypass some very important guardrails so it's up to you to make sure that the road is safe.

You can create a new function that uses an autonomous transaction

```
create or replace function MakeDeepLinkExAut( p_user_id integer,
                                              p_ad_id   integer )
  return varchar2
as
  l_retvar varchar2(500);
  pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
  l_retvar := pbweb.adposter.MakeDeepLinkEx(p_user_id, p_ad_id);
  commit;
  return l_retvar;
end;
```

and then call this new function in your `select` statement.

Comment: MakeDeepLinkEx generates a link and saves an id into a table hence the error i am getting.

Comment: @user794846 - Right.  But what impact does that have on the system as a whole?  What happens if you call the function for a row that should be invisible or which doesn't meet the date criteria?  Does that mean that a link exists for an invisible campaign that is supposed to be over?  The optimizer is free to call functions on rows that are filtered out of the final results because it assumes that functions have no side effects.  If you want functions to have side-effects, you're responsible for making sure that nothing the optimizer does creates problems for your system.

Comment: Yeah it shouldn't based on the where clause. Can i create this function on the fly in my php script inside a db_prepare($sql) (prepared statement) or something I dont want to alter or have to recompile any of the plsql source code to over come this. I want to be able to do it all in the script that creates calls this query if possible

Comment: @user794846 - That's what I'm saying.  The optimizer is absolutely allowed to call the function before evaluating any or all predicates in the `where` clause.  So it is absolutely allowed to call the function for an invisible campaign with a date in the future and then filter that row out later.  But the link would still be created and committed.  You're responsible for making sure those side effects don't harm the system.  It wouldn't make structural sense but syntactically, sure, you could create the function each time your script is run.

Comment: Thanks I think this has solved the issue. I get what your saying about the need to fully understand what the function does etc. I agree with you, its just that this is a really old legacy system using a 20 year db. Nobody is that concerned as long as the immediate issue was resolved.